# Idea for doing almost same work in both catch & finally(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a requirement.

I am processing some files and after the processing are done I am archiving those files into an archive folder with timestamp appended.

The file archiving and putting time stamp portion I am doing in the Finally block. Now a new requirement has come where I need to mail if something wrong goes in the original files and then I need to archive the same. Now this piece of code I need to handle in the catch block.

But if I write the code entirely in the catch block, then it will fire only if there is an exception; otherwise not.

So basically I am writing the same pice of code in both the catch and finally block.

What is the standard and recommended approach you people think will be better in this case?

I am using C#3.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A finally block is really for code that "always" has to run, even after an exception. This typically means cleanup type code. It's a "code smell" to see processing type code in a finally block.

Maybe you can post your code, and we can suggest a better way for you.